# Errors in Dual boot windows 7 and windows 10 with legacy bios and MBR partitions

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, boot, partitioning, multi-boot

I had installed windows 7 and and windows 10 on my SSD in two different partitions.I am using Legacy boot option in bios and my SSD using MBR instead of GPT.

Problem i am facing is that when i turn on the pc or restart pc to switch from one windows to another, sometimes it boots perfectly without any error and sometimes it get stuck on windows loading screen. I have to manually power off and turn the pc on again, and then it loads the same windows without any problem. Some times it successfully load windows after first attempt and sometimes i have to do it multiple times. It does not matter which windows i am loading (7/10) same issue happens again and again. i am not sure what is causing this issue but i suspect corrupted "Boot Configuration Data".

I dont want to reinstall both windows. Appreciate in anyone can help me diagnosing/resolving the issue.

i am attaching screenshot of bcdedit and list of volumes.
[bcdedit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blvRF.jpg)
[volumes/partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VZPJ.jpg)

Comment: We prefer that you post supplementary textual information as text.

Comment: How long is it getting stuck? How long do you wait before shutting down?

Comment: Once its stuck it freezes for forever, longest i waited before restarting is 20 mins , on average i wait for 5-8 mins before restarting.